# $R$ is an integral domain iff $R[x_1,...,x_n]$ is a integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I would like to prove that $R$ is an integral domain iff $R[x_1,...,x_n]$ is a integral domain. The converse is trivial, since R can be viewed as a subring of $R[x_1,...,x_n]$. In order to prove the first implication, I'm trying to use the same argument we use when we prove the case $n=1$ looking to the highest degree coefficient, am I on the right way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you prove the case $n=1$? If so, then you're done. Suppose $R$ in an integral domain, and inductively assume $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is an integral domain. Then $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1}] = R[x_1,\ldots,x_n][x_{n+1}]$ is an integral domain since $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is.

Answer (score 3):

$$R[x_1,x_2]=R[x_1][x_2]$$
So if you can handle the one-variable case, you're done by induction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if I would like to prove the general case directly can I prove directly looking into the highest degree coefficient?

Comment: There isn't a unique "highest degree coefficient" when $n>1$. What is the highest degree coefficient of $3xy^2+2x^2y$ in $\mathbb Z[x,y]$? @user74141

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, it's true

Answer (score 1):

If you already have proved this assertion for $n=1$ then you can use the induction since $R[x_1,...,x_n]=(R[x_1,...,x_{n-1}])[x_n]$.